# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I installed mysql@5.7 on Mac OS Monterey with

> homebrew install mysql@5.7

but when I try mysql -u root after a successful brew services start mysql@5.7 I get the following error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Checking the status using brew list has it as 'stopped' even immediately after what appears to be a successful start. I've tried reinstalling, including deleting:

/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

/opt/homebrew/var/mysql

But I'm still getting the same issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: Any informations in the log of mysql server?

Comment: there a lots if tutorials about homebriew and mysql, which did  you use? there is ussually more steps to it

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/macoclock/installing-mysql-5-7-using-homebrew-974cc2d42509 but copied the install commands straight from the homebrew webpage to make sure there weren't any mistakes.